# Why does Sonic refer to Robotnik as Eggman?

Tags: dialogue, sonic-the-hedgehog

In the movie *Sonic The Hedgehog* there are two scenes where Sonic refers to Robotnik as Eggman. Apart from it being a reference to his Japanese video game name, why does Sonic do that? Was there any explanation in the movie, as I thought it came out of nowhere. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doctor Ivo "Eggman" Robotnik is the character's name from the original japanese *Sonic the Hedgehog* game series.

When Sonic calls him Eggman it's also a reference to the egg-shape drones that Robotnik uses throughout the movie.

Take that as an easter egg (pun intended).

Comment: I don't remember the exact line, but I believe Sonic does refer to Robotnik's drones being egg-shaped immediately before he calls him "Eggman" for the first time. It's also nicely foreshadowed by him referring to Tom and Maddie as "Donut Lord" and "Pretzel Lady" respectively.

Comment: @F1Krazy that makes sense

Comment: @F1Krazy is correct, the drones looked like flying eggs, so sonic called him Eggman. Sonic was big on nick names... e.g. hence why Tom was called "Donut lord" because he ate Donuts and talked to them.

Comment: @Jared that's what I said in my answer...